# Tuple struct constructor complains about private fields

Tags: rust, private, tuple-struct

I am working on a basic shell interpreter to familiarize myself with Rust. While working on the table for storing suspended jobs in the shell, I have gotten stuck at the following compiler error message:

```
error: cannot invoke tuple struct constructor with private fields [E0450]
     let jobs = job::JobsList(vec![]);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It's unclear to me what is being seen as private here. As you can see below, both of the  structs are tagged with `pub` in my module file. So, what's the secret sauce?

```
mod job {
    use std::fmt;

    pub struct Job {
        jid: isize,
        pid: isize,
        cmd: String,
    }

    pub struct JobsList(Vec<Job>);
}

fn main() {
    let jobs = job::JobsList(vec![]);
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

As the error message suggests, the problem is `JobsList` has a private field, that is, the `Vec<Job>` value is inaccessible outside the module that defines the `struct`. This means that you cannot pattern match on a `JobsList` value to extract it, and that you cannot construct it directly.

There are two fixes:

- make the field public `pub struct JobsList(pub Vec<Job>);`
- provide a public constructor

  ```rust
    impl JobsList {
        pub fn new(jobs: Vec<Job>) -> JobsList {
            JobsList(jobs)
        }
    }
  ```

  called like `JobsList::new(vec![])`.

Answer (score 3):

The same error can be caused by using a Box pointer with incorrect syntax.

```
    let list_node_5 = ListNode::new(5, None);
    
    //CORRECT SYNTAX: 
    let list_node_4 = ListNode::new(4, Some(Box::new(list_node_5)));
    
    //INCORRECT SYNTAX: 
    let list_node_4 = ListNode::new(4, Some(Box(list_node_5));
```

Complete context: manually building a linked list for testing a LeetCode problem. https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/

```
    pub struct ListNode {
      val: i32,
      next: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
    }
    
    impl ListNode {
      pub fn new(val: i32, next: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Self {
        ListNode {
          val,
          next,
        }
      }
      //[...]
    }
    
    fn main() {
      let list_node_5 = ListNode::new(5, None);
      let list_node_4 = ListNode::new(4, Some(Box::new(list_node_5)));
      let list_node_4 = ListNode::new(4, Some(Box(list_node_5));
      
      //[...]
      
    }
```